# How to pass variable with ajax to blade Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I want when i select dropdown and pick team to list player who play in that team and only to give me back that specific players...I do this bellow , but i don't know how to send variable from ajax direct in blade and after that to do my thing with foreach :) ... Thanks a lot ...

This is my blade

```
{!! Form::open(array('url'=>'','files'=>'true')) !!}

                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 mb-2">
                            {!! Form::select('category',[''=>'Chose Team to See Players']+$teams, null,['class'=>'form-control','id'=>'category']) !!}

                        </div>

                        {!! Form::close() !!}
                    </div>
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead class="bg-yellow bg-lighten-3">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Photo</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Position</th>
                                <th>Age</th>
                                <th>Edit</th>
                                <th>Delete</th>
                                <th>Add/Edit Biography</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            @foreach($players as $player)

                                <tr>
                                    <td><img src="{{$player->photo->file}}" alt="cukaricki-{{$player->playerName}}" width="150px"></td>
                                    <td>{{$player->playerName}} {{$player->playerLastName}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$player->position}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$player->age}}</td>
                                    <td> {!! Form::open(['method'=>'GET','action'=>['PlayerController@edit',$player->id]]) !!}

                                        <div class="class form-group">
                                            {!! Form::submit('Edit',['class'=>'badge btn-info btn-sm']) !!}
                                        </div>

                                        {!! Form::close() !!}</td>

                                    <td>

                                        {!! Form::open(['method'=>'DELETE','action'=>['PlayerController@destroy',$player->id]]) !!}

                                        <div class="class form-group">
                                            {!! Form::submit('Delete',['class'=>'badge btn-danger btn-sm']) !!}
                                        </div>

                                        {!! Form::close() !!}
                                    </td>


                                        @if($player->checkBiography($player->id) == false)

                                        <td>
                                            {!! Form::open(['method'=>'GET','action'=>['BiographyController@show',$player->id]]) !!}

                                            <div class="class form-group">
                                                {!! Form::submit('Create',['class'=>'badge btn-success btn-sm']) !!}
                                            </div>

                                            {!! Form::close() !!}</td>

                                           @else
                                        <td>
                                        {!! Form::open(['method'=>'GET','action'=>['BiographyController@edit',$player->id]]) !!}

                                        <div class="class form-group">
                                            {!! Form::submit('Edit',['class'=>'badge btn-warning btn-sm']) !!}
                                        </div>

                                        {!! Form::close() !!}</td>
                                    @endif

                                </tr>

                            @endforeach

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
```

Route

```
Route::get('/ajax-subcat',function (){

    $cat_id = Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::get('cat_id');

    $team=App\Team::where('id',$cat_id)->first();

    $arrays=explode(",",$team->player_id);

    foreach($arrays as $array){
        $players[]=App\Player::where('id',$array)->first();

    }
    return Response::json($players);

});
```

And Ajax:

```
<script>

    $('#category').on('change',function (e) {

        console.log(e);

        var cat_id = e.target.value;

        //ajax

        $.get('/ajax-subcat?cat_id='+cat_id,function (data) {

            //success data
            $('#ovde').empty();
            $.each(data,function (index,  Obj) {
```

//what to do here how to send $players from route to blade ?!

```
                );
            });


        });

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is create a partial blade of the following code and call it, "player_list.blade.php".

```
@foreach($players as $player)

                            <tr>
                                <td><img src="{{$player->photo->file}}" alt="cukaricki-{{$player->playerName}}" width="150px"></td>
                                <td>{{$player->playerName}} {{$player->playerLastName}}</td>
                                <td>{{$player->position}}</td>
                                <td>{{$player->age}}</td>
                                <td> {!! Form::open(['method'=>'GET','action'=>['PlayerController@edit',$player->id]]) !!}

                                    <div class="class form-group">
                                        {!! Form::submit('Edit',['class'=>'badge btn-info btn-sm']) !!}
                                    </div>

                                    {!! Form::close() !!}</td>

                                <td>

                                    {!! Form::open(['method'=>'DELETE','action'=>['PlayerController@destroy',$player->id]]) !!}

                                    <div class="class form-group">
                                        {!! Form::submit('Delete',['class'=>'badge btn-danger btn-sm']) !!}
                                    </div>

                                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                                </td>


                                    @if($player->checkBiography($player->id) == false)

                                    <td>
                                        {!! Form::open(['method'=>'GET','action'=>['BiographyController@show',$player->id]]) !!}

                                        <div class="class form-group">
                                            {!! Form::submit('Create',['class'=>'badge btn-success btn-sm']) !!}
                                        </div>

                                        {!! Form::close() !!}</td>

                                       @else
                                    <td>
                                    {!! Form::open(['method'=>'GET','action'=>['BiographyController@edit',$player->id]]) !!}

                                    <div class="class form-group">
                                        {!! Form::submit('Edit',['class'=>'badge btn-warning btn-sm']) !!}
                                    </div>

                                    {!! Form::close() !!}</td>
                                @endif

                            </tr>

                        @endforeach
```

Then in your routes anonymous method, render that view and send rendered html instead of sending back json.

Use following code

```
$viewRendered = view('player_list', compact('players'))->render();
return Resposne::json(['html'=>$viewRendered]);
```

Instead of

```
return Response::json($players);
```

This way you can pass any variable to your views.

Comment: Do i need to pass whole blade or just foreach - endforeach ? Do i need in my main blade to delete all inside foreach ? Should i modify previous ajax ? Thanks a lot man...

Comment: I include player_list.blade.php with only foreach inside and my players dont change...But when i go to inspect and look in network he give me good preview of tables but not change in main blade..Maybe i need to flash this change every time i use ajax ?

Comment: first of all change your main blade as well, now include your newly created partial in that main blade. (reuse the partial).

Secondly give your tobody tag an id, and using jquery either replace its content or append after last tr tag, it depends on your need. so you don't need .each now.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to clear the tr's in table body, and append new ones with the data you receive.

Inside your javascript loop you can create a string containing your  and s.

```
var photo = '<td>' + obj.photo  + '</td>';
var name = '<td>' + obj.name + '</td>';
...
...
var playerRow = '<tr>' + photo + name + etc... + '</tr>';

$("#yourTable > tbody:last").append(playerRow);
```

It's a bit tedious. You might consider using a framework like Vuejs, or whatever you choose. It simplifies a lot these tasks